# python pandas quick convert to datetime, 1.5 million rows

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I have a large dataframe, 1.5million rows, see the snapshot below. I want to create a date-time column by combing date and time column (both are strings), when i create a column of data-time together after parsing, it takes me ages as operation is carried out on each row individually.

```
              Date          Time  Open 
Symbol                                                                         
VOD   02/25/2013  00:00:00.000     0 
VOD   02/25/2013  00:01:00.000     0 
VOD   02/25/2013  00:02:00.000     0 
VOD   02/25/2013  00:03:00.000     0 
VOD   02/25/2013  00:04:00.000     0 
VOD   02/25/2013  00:05:00.000     0 
VOD   02/25/2013  00:06:00.000     0
```

I am using the following code to create a column

```
aa=[datetime.strptime(str(df.DateMap[i])+' '+df.Time[i], '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f') for i in range(len(df))]
```

This function takes ages to complete as there are 1.5 million rows. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

```
In [1]: data = """VOD   02/25/2013  00:00:00.000     0 
VOD   02/25/2013  00:01:00.000     0 
VOD   02/25/2013  00:02:00.000     0 
VOD   02/25/2013  00:03:00.000     0 
VOD   02/25/2013  00:04:00.000     0 
VOD   02/25/2013  00:05:00.000     0 
VOD   02/25/2013  00:06:00.000     0 """

In [2]: df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data),sep='\s+',names=['ticker','date','time','value'])

In [3]: df2 = pd.concat([df]*100000*2)

In [4]: df2.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 1400000 entries, 0 to 6
Data columns (total 4 columns):
ticker    1400000 non-null object
date      1400000 non-null object
time      1400000 non-null object
value     1400000 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(1), object(3)
memory usage: 53.4+ MB

In [5]: result1 = pd.to_datetime(df2['date'] + ' ' + df2['time'],format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')

In [6]: result2 = pd.to_datetime(df2['date'], format="%m/%d/%Y") +  pd.to_timedelta(df2['time'])
result1
In [7]: result1.equals(result2)
Out[7]: True

In [9]: result1.head()
Out[9]: 
0   2013-02-25 00:00:00
1   2013-02-25 00:01:00
2   2013-02-25 00:02:00
3   2013-02-25 00:03:00
4   2013-02-25 00:04:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Here are 2 methods, In this case it pays to parse all at once (e.g. 4). Note that this is with master, 0.16.2 will be a bit slower on the timedelta parsing.

```
In [5]: %timeit pd.to_datetime(df2['date'], format="%m/%d/%Y") +  pd.to_timedelta(df2['time'])
1 loops, best of 3: 9.76 s per loop

In [4]: %timeit pd.to_datetime(df2['date'] + ' ' + df2['time'],format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')
1 loops, best of 3: 8.81 s per loop
```